# Doctrine PHPCR-ODM throws "Transport does not support versioning" exception

Tags: symfony, doctrine-phpcr

The past few days I've been really interested in `PHPCR` and how it could be used to track versions of `Documents`. Unfortunately it seems I can't manage to get the versioning to work with `Doctrine` in `PostgreSQL` for some reason.

According to the documentation of [phpcr](http://phpcr.readthedocs.org/en/latest/book/versioning.html) and [doctrine](http://doctrine-phpcr-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/versioning.html), `simpleVersioning` should be working just fine, but when I try to create a `checkpoint` I receive the following exception:

```
Transport does not support versioning
in vendor/jackalope/jackalope/src/Jackalope/Workspace.php at line 294
```

I'm kind of confused what seems to be the problem here and why this is failing? Here is my document:

```
use Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Mapping\Annotations as PHPCR;

/**
 * @PHPCR\Document(versionable="simple")
 */
class Task {

    /**
     * @PHPCR\Id()
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @PHPCR\String()
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @PHPCR\Boolean()
     */
    protected $done = false;

    /**
     * @PHPCR\ParentDocument()
     */
    protected $parentDocument;

    /**
     * @PHPCR\VersionName()
     */
    private $versionName;

    /**
     * @PHPCR\VersionCreated()
     */
    private $versionCreated;

    /* Getters and setters for all fields... */
}
```

And here is the code I'm using in a controller:

```
/**
 * @var DocumentManager $dm
 */
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_phpcr')->getManager();

$rootTask = $dm->find(null, '/tasks');
$task = new Task();
$task->setDescription('Finish CMF project');
$task->setParentDocument($rootTask);
$dm->persist($task);
$dm->flush();

$dm->checkpoint($task);

$task->setDescription("Some new description");
$dm->persist($task);
$dm->flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears I have mislead myself to believing this is supported in the database. In this moment the version support is only available if you're using jackrabbit. Feature support list is available [here](http://phpcr.github.io/implementations/).